# Can jQuery go to another page, and grab like 10 links, and use them on the first page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, userscripts

Okay my title might be a bit misleading/not too understandable, so I'll try and explain here what I want to do. I'm only curious if it's possible, I couldn't find too much info about it, so no, I have not tried to do something yet, but I am not asking you to do it for me either. (common replies when you ask a question here)

So basically, let's say I am at the index page of a site, and let's say there is like 5 users who have posted something and they're all lined up.

```
Blabla1 has posted a new thread.
Blabla2 has posted a new thread.
Blabla3 has posted a new thread.
Blabla4 has posted a new thread.
Blabla5 has posted a new thread.
```

And if I click on this, it would bring me to their thread, along with their profile information. (I.E Skype add-me button/link)

Is it possible to make a jQuery script to go to this profile/thread page and grab the Skype add-me link and have it printed out on the first page (index) for those 5 people?
Example:

```
Blabla1 has posted a new thread. (Skype link here)
Blabla2 has posted a new thread. (Skype link here)
Blabla3 has posted a new thread. (Skype link here)
Blabla4 has posted a new thread. (Skype link here)
Blabla5 has posted a new thread. (Skype link here)
```

I am not asking anyone to do this for me, I only want to know if it's possible for jQuery to do such thing, and if so, point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Sorry, forgot to include that it's not my site, this would be for a userscript.

Comment: You could use [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) but if you are generating these pages then it would be better to add the info server side.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that it's not my site, this would be for a userscript. Thanks for the reply tho.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Try it out and ask a question if you have a problem. Another comment people always write... But that's how stack overflow works

Comment: @JuanMendes I was just stating to avoid "try it or gtfo", but as I had searched around and couldn't find what I was looking for (as you can see I was not too good at explaining it, at least not with the title) I didn't know how I would try something out before asking, or alike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.get()` to fetch the page (the another page) content, and then use `$.parseHTML()` to parse the html DOM nodes.

```
$.get('/path/to/another/page.html', function(data) {
    html = $.parseHTML(data);

    // Show the parsed HTML's node names
    $.each(html, function(i, el) {
        alert(el.innerHTML);
    });
});
```

Ref:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Comment: Thanks for this, will be useful. Do you know why this RegExp fails? (works if I do not use .match part)

http://pastebin.com/aG2Q4hLw

It would log "/" if not using .match, but I'm trying to get the "t" ID of each href.

Comment: `$('a')` is getting al `<a>` from the current page, so if your page contains many links, `$('a').attr('href')` won't work.

Comment: better ask in a new question :(